# Decreasing sequence of bounded closed sets with lower bounded diameters

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(E, \|\cdot\|)$ be a real normed space, and let $(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a decreasing sequence of bounded closed subsets of $E$. Assume moreover that there is a real $r>0$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\mathrm{diam}(A_n) > r$.

Do we have then $\mathrm{diam} \Big( \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n \Big) \geq r$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

Consider the normed space $\ell^2$ and the canonical basis $(e_n)_n$.

Define $A_n = \{e_n, e_{n+1}, \ldots\}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Clearly $(A_n)_n$ is a decreasing sequence.

We have $\|e_n\|_2 = 1, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ so $A_n$ are bounded. Also we have $\|e_n - e_m\|_2 = 1, \forall m \ne n$ so $A_n$ are discrete and hence closed. We see that  $\operatorname{diam} A_n = 1> \frac12$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

However, $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n = \emptyset$ so $\operatorname{diam} \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n = 0$ which is not $\ge \frac12$.

This construction can be done in any infinite-dimensional normed space using the Riesz lemma.

---

The statement is still seems false if we require $A_n$ to be convex sets: just take the closure of the convex hull $\overline{\operatorname{conv} A_n}$ of the sets defined above. The resulting sequence is still a decreasing sequence of closed bounded sets (as they are contained in the unit ball of $\ell^2$) which are now convex, and with diameter $> \frac12$ but we still have $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \overline{\operatorname{conv} A_n} = \emptyset$.

However, if we require the space $E$ to be finite-dimensional, then the statement is true:

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ since $\operatorname{diam} A_n > r$ we can choose $x_n, y_n \in A_n$ such that $d(x_n, y_n) > r$.

$A_1$ is a closed and bounded set and hence compact (by finite-dimensionality). Hence the sequences $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)_n$ in $A_1$ have limit points in $A_1$, i.e. there exist subsequences $(x_{p(n)})_n$ and $(y_{p(n)})_n$ such that $x_{p(n)} \to x$ and $y_{p(n)} \to y$ with $x,y \in A_1$.

Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and notice that $\left(x_{p(n)}\right)_{n=m}^\infty$ and $\left(y_{p(n)}\right)_{n=m}^\infty$ are sequences in $A_m$ which clearly converge to $x$ and $y$ respectively. Since $A_m$ is closed we have $x,y \in A_m$.
Therefore, $x,y \in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n$ and by the continuity of the metric

$$\underbrace{d\left(x_{p(n)}, y_{p(n)}\right)}_{> r} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} d(x,y)$$

We conclude $d(x,y) \ge r$ so $\operatorname{diam} \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n \ge r$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea about the above statement holding if we moreover assume every $A_n$ to be convex? And does it hold in a finite dimensional space too?

Comment: @ztn3dm1 See the edit. I'm not really sure how to prove that $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \overline{\operatorname{conv} A_n} = \emptyset$ but it seems intuitively obvious.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If we could prove that $\mathrm{span} \{ e_k, k \geq n \}$ is a closed subspace of $E$, then $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \overline{\mathrm{conv} A_n \,} = \emptyset$ follows since $\mathrm{conv} A_n \subset \mathrm{span} \{ e_k, k \geq n \}$.

Comment: Alright, $\mathrm{span} \{ e_k, k \geq n \}$ is indeed closed. If we take a sequence $(x_p)_{p \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\mathrm{span} \{ e_k, k \geq n \}$ such that $(x_p) \xrightarrow[]{} x \in E$, then we have for all $k<n$: $\langle x, e_k \rangle = \lim_{p\to\infty} \langle x_p, e_k \rangle = 0$. Therefore $x \in \mathrm{span} \{ e_k, k \geq n \}$.

Comment: @ztn3dm1 You are probably thinking about $\overline{\operatorname{span}\{e_k : k \ge n\}}$ as the above subspace isn't closed because it has countably infinite dimension and is a subspace of a Banach space. But I agree, clearly $$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \overline{\operatorname{conv} A_n} \subseteq \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \overline{\operatorname{span}\{e_k : k \ge n\}} = \{0\}$$ so it only remains to show that $0$ is not in the intersection (which is pretty clear because all $e_n$ have nonnegative coordinates).

Comment: You'r right, $\mathrm{span} \{ e_k, n \geq n \}$ can't be closed. My mistake comes from $(e_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ being a Hilbert basis, but not a Hamel basis. Thanks for your answer.